# Why this data binding in aspx does not work?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, data-binding, .net-2.0

I have this following data source binding:

```
MembershipProvider provider = new MembershipProvider();
UserUpdateLogs userUpdateLogs = provider.GetUserUpdateLogs(username);

dgUserUpdateLog.DataSource = userUpdateLogs.Logs;
dgUserUpdateLog.DataBind();
```

**Logs** is a collection of **UserUpdateLogEntry**. This class owns the **UserData** Property, and UserData contains other properties. My aspx:

```
<Columns>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="ChangeDate" Visible="true" HeaderText="Date"/>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="UserData.Sex" HeaderText="Sex" />
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="UserData.Phone" HeaderText="Phone" />
</Columns>
```

The first row (**ChangeDate**) seems to work well. But when rendering the second BoundColumn, the following error is shown:

> A field or property with the name
>   'UserData.Sex' was not found on the
>   selected data source.

Why does it happen? Can't Aspx recognize a concatenation of properties like PropertyA.PropertyB?

I've checked the object and all properties have valid data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not bind to properties of sub-objects in that way.

As an alternative, you can use a template column and use Eval to display the properties of the sub-object, e.g. something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Sex" Visible="true">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserData.Sex") %>' /> 
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Phone" Visible="true">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserData.Phone") %>' /> 
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you can do is create an accessor property:

```
public string UserSex
{
    get { return userUpdateLogs.Logs.UserData.Sex; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is using reflection to look for a property called `UserData.Sex`, it is not smart enough to search for `UserData` and then `Sex`.
So the answer to your question is 'No'.

There are several ways to get around this, but the more elegant ways are either to add a property UserSex, or to flatten the object into a data table. At the moment, I can't think of a good way that doesn't break OO.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what to tell you about why it won't work, but a workaround to write this might be to use some linq2objects:

```
dgUserUpdateLog.DataSource = (from n in userUpdateLogs.Logs select new {n.ChangeDate, Sex=n.Userdata.Sex, Phone=n.UserData.Phone});
```

then:

```
<Columns>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="ChangeDate" Visible="true" HeaderText="Date"/>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Sex" HeaderText="Sex" />
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Phone" HeaderText="Phone" />
</Columns>
```

Comment: I am using .net 2.0, otherwise it could be a good workaround, thanks!